# PIG: how to choose good value for PARALLEL clause?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, workflow, cloudera

I'm trying to minimize for a given cluster (512GB RAM, 100 vCores) the execution time of a workflow with multiples "instances" of the same PIG script.

Increasing PARALLEL clause value for COGROUP operations give better results. However, is there a formula to pick up good value for such clause ? PIG documentation is very evasive about that!

Comment: what is the HDFS block size?

Comment: Hello, the HDFS block size is 1GB, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the is no firm rule to define number of reducers and it more can be done empirically investigating the COGROUP execution time phase and playing with different values for PARALELL(suggest to start with 100 from my experience).

Nevertheless the upper bound is usually defined as numReduces << heapSize/(2*io.buffer.size). More you can find [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces)